# access violation in module 'bds.exe' when connecting to access database using 'firedac'

Tags: delphi, access-violation, firedac

I have done extensive research looking for a solution for this. I know that this error is not in my code. I can create a new project with only the TFDconnection Component attempt to connect to a new access database and I still receive and Access violation error. I have reinstalled Rad Studio 10.3 but the problem persist. Any help trouble shooting this would be appreciated.

```
function TODBCConnection.DriverConnect(const AConnString: String;
  ADriverCompletion: SQLUSmallint; AParentWnd: SQLHWnd): String;
var
  iOutConnStrLen: SQLSmallint;
{$IFDEF FireDAC_MONITOR}
  s: String;
  i1, i2: Integer;
{$ENDIF}
begin
{$IFDEF FireDAC_MONITOR}
  if Tracing then begin
    s := AConnString;
    i1 := Pos('PWD=', UpperCase(s));
    if i1 <> 0 then begin
      i2 := Pos(';', s, i1);
      if i2 = 0 then
        i2 := Length(s) + 1;
      Inc(i1, 4);
      while i1 < i2 do begin
        s[i1] := '*';
        Inc(i1);
      end;
    end;
    Trace(ekVendor, esProgress, 'SQLDriverConnect', ['szConnStr', s]);
  end;
{$ENDIF}
  SetLength(Result, C_RETURNED_STRING_MAXLEN);
  FillChar(Result[1], C_RETURNED_STRING_MAXLEN * SizeOf(Char), 0);
  iOutConnStrLen := 0;

-> Check(Lib.SQLDriverConnect(FHandle, AParentWnd, PSQLChar(AConnString), 
SQL_NTS,
    PSQLChar(Result), C_RETURNED_STRING_MAXLEN, iOutConnStrLen, 
ADriverCompletion));
  FConnected := True;
  AfterConnect;
  ODBCSetLength(Result, iOutConnStrLen);
end;
```

The exception points to line show after -> "I apologize I am not sure how to correctly post the error line"

Comment: Isn't there exception stack trace in Delphi, based upon Jedi CodeLib? There was in XE2. And AnyDAC was shipped with sources, when it was a standalone library. I don't know if FireDAC sources are installed together with RTL/VCL/FMX sources now. So, as a general approach, you take the exception stack trace, you take FireDAC sources - and match together. If you can repro the AV in your project, yet better, then go into Project Options, tick *Use Debug DCUs* and rebuild. Now run the project in IDE and it should open FireDAc sources in the place of the exception.

Comment: Since you are getting the AV in Bds.Exe, I assume it happens when you try to set the FDConnection's Connected property to True.  Do you also get te error if you set Connected to True at run-time using code in your app?

Comment: Yes I do. I will post the exception string above.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The problem was with the MSAccess driver Official download here -> [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13255) After reinstalling I am able to connect again with out error.

Comment: Thank everyone for your time.

Comment: Glad you solved it yourself and well done for taking the trouble to post an answer.